# method getHomeworkSum() returns lastest homework value, not the sum

Tags: java, methods

There are two classes. class 1 has the methods. class 2 calls the methods. I will show you the part of class 1 that i need help on, but will include the entirety of class 2 since it is much shorter than class 2.

class 1

```
public void setHomeworkSum() {
        homeworkSum =+ homeworkScore;
    }

    public int getHomeworkSum() {
        return homeworkSum;
    }
```

class 2

```
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
 import java.util.Scanner;


 public class CourseGrade {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    Student myStudent = new Student();


    myStudent.openFile();

    myStudent.setNumberOfStudents();

    System.out.format("%-10s %25s %15s %10s", "Name", "Assignment score", "Test score", "Grade\n");
    System.out.println();

    for(int i = 1; i <= myStudent.getNumberOfStudents(); i++){

    myStudent.setDefault();

    myStudent.setFirstName();

    myStudent.setLastName();

    myStudent.setHomeworkScore();

    myStudent.setTestScore();

    myStudent.setHomeworkScore();

    myStudent.setTestScore();

    myStudent.computeGrade();


    System.out.format("%-19s %1s %21s %13s", myStudent.getFirstName() + " " +      myStudent.getLastName(), myStudent.getHomeworkScore(), myStudent.getTestScore(), myStudent.getGrade() +"\n");

    myStudent.setPassFail();

    myStudent.setHomeworkSum();

    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("No. of students passed: " + myStudent.getPass());
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("No. of students failed: " + myStudent.getFail());
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("sum: " + myStudent.getHomeworkSum());

}
```

}

basically, the problem i'm having is it doesn't return the sum of all the homeworkscores, but instead returns the latest individual homeworkscore that was read.

```
Output:

Name                Assignment score      Test score     Grade

Anthony Hopkins     854                   284            G
John Smith          730                   214            A
Pan Mei             730                   267            A
Rafael Vega         801                   236            A

No. of students passed: 4

No. of students failed: 0

mean 801
```

(the top part didn't convert correctly, but you get the idea.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change to

```
homeworkSum += homeworkScore;
```

You had

```
homeworkSum =+ homeworkScore;
```

which, if you put some space, basically is

```
homeworkSum = +homeworkScore;
```

so you are always assigning the last value to the variable.